# Cleanly exit from python publisher ensuring all messages sent

Tags: ros, rospy, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working on a Python node that essentially publishes one-off messages and then exits. Due, I believe, to the threading in rospy, messages are not always sent if the script exits soon after publishing a message. I have also found no ways of truly guaranteeing that messages that sent messages are received.

Here is some example code based roughly on the nodes demonstrated in the ROS tutorials:

### Publisher

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from std_msgs.msg import Header
import rospy
import math

topic = 'foo'

publisher = rospy.Publisher(topic, Header, queue_size = 10)

rospy.init_node('publisher',anonymous = True)

msg = Header()
msg.frame_id = "Hello World!"
publisher.publish(msg)
```

### Subscriber:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Header

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id()+"I heard %s",data.frame_id)
    
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber("foo", Header, callback)

    rospy.spin()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

There are a number of modifications I have found that will get the messages to send:

1. Use a rospy.Rate object with sufficiently low rate and sleep after publishing
2. Sending messages in a loop with no other calls to ROS functionality will result in most messages being received.
3. *edit* I tried a loop `while not rorpy.is_shutdown()` containing `rospy.signal_shutdown('stuff')` after the message is sent. This method results in the message being received some of the time.

There are also some exceptions where the message may otherwise be expected to be received:

1. Sleeping using a rospy.Duration object will not allow sends to complete
2. rospy.signal_shutdown does not guarantee that pending messages are sent
3. Pending sends are not completed when using a Rate object with too high a rate

On top of all this, I have found that `rostopic echo` will often (but not always) get messages when a subscribing node does not.

I would like to know if there is any (hopefully documented) way that I can exit a python script with the guarantee that every subscriber to a topic that node publishes will have received every message that has been published. So far I have not been able to find anything to this effect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182894/cleanly-exit-from-python-publisher-ensuring-all-messages-sent/) by [micah.corah](https://answers.ros.org/users/19437/micah.corah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to make sure a message was sent, the simplest solution is to check that it was received. Have your node subscribe to the topic you're publishing on, and exit when it receives a message. However, topics in ROS aren't really designed to be used this way. If you want to be really sure your message has been received, this is what [services](http://wiki.ros.org/Services) are for.

Alternatively, depending on the data type, your node could set a parameter with its data on the parameter server rather than publishing. This data would then be available for any node that wanted it even after the publishing node shuts down.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-07-03**:
Adding on what @dan-lazewatsky said, many people have had problems creating a publisher, and then immediately publishing. If you only want to publish once, and then exit, you might want to also consider adding a delay between publisher creation and message publishing.

**Comment by [micah.corah](https://answers.ros.org/users/19437/micah.corah/) on 2014-07-03**:
What I have been seeing is that some subscribers will get a message but not others so self-subscribing provides no guarantee (i.e. "rostopic echo" may get messages when another node doesn't)

Good point about services, I was planning the switch.

A delay may fix that problem, but it would be a hack.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the actual semantics of the message being sent, does it have some set lifetime? One possible option here would be for the publisher to be set to "latched" and then have the node only sleep for the "valid lifetime" of the message that is latched. By latching the message, you avoid the issues with subscribers not connecting quickly enough between the time of advertisement and before publication of the message.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question:

I found my answer in the rospy source. There is a comment that explicitly states that sending of all messages before shutdown is not guaranteed. Instead, there is a check for whether the process is still running before writing, and if not it exits immediately.

Here is an excerpt from `topics.py`

```
 except ValueError:
        # operations on self.buff can fail if topic is closed
        # during publish, which often happens during Ctrl-C.
        # diagnose the error and report accordingly.
        if self.closed:
            if is_shutdown():
                # we offer no guarantees on publishes that occur
                # during shutdown, so this is not exceptional.
                return
```

---

Originally posted by [micah.corah](https://answers.ros.org/users/19437/micah.corah/) with karma: 66 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2